# How to show only the center of div when window size is smaller

Tags: jquery, css, flash, web

I am messing with [this site](http://galant-jeans.x10.mx)!
And I want to keep the flash object centered, even when the window size is smaller than 1280, so it only shows the center of the div. I hope you know what I'm asking for. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it :

```
#flashContent
{
position: absolute;
top: 180px;
left: 50%;
width : 1280px;
margin-left: -640px; // half of 1280px
}
```

Comment: Thirtydot answered first, he should get the kudos. But thanks.